# How to remove a substring from string of particular index to some length in swift

Tags: swift, string, substring

I have a string let's say,

```
var myString = "thisIsMyAutoGeneratedRandomString"
```

I want to remove some characters from index 8 to 26, let's say.
I need the out put like

```
print(myString)   //thisIsMyString  --> This is what i want.
```

I tried `base1.remove(at: base1.index(i: String.Index, offsetBy: String.IndexDistance))` as `base1.remove(at: base1.index(i: 8, offsetBy: 26))`

but i am getting warning like
`Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String.Index'`

I tried lot of things but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myString = "thisIsMyAutoGeneratedRandomString"

let ix = myString.startIndex // the index of 1st character
let ix2 = myString.index(ix, offsetBy: 8) // the index of 8th character
let ix3 = myString.index(ix, offsetBy: 26) // the index of 26th character

myString.removeSubrange(ix2...ix3)

print(myString) //thisIsMyString
```

Comment: This works. Thanks @Roman Ryzhiy. But i created an extension following the same thing you provided.

`mutating func remove(from:Int, length:Int){
let range = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: from)..<self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: length+from)
self.removeSubrange(range)
 }`

Comment: @Ravi Everybody does the same immediately after they understand the difference between `Int` and `String.Index`

Comment: alternatively: **myString = String(myString.prefix(myString.count - 2)) //trim last 2**

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `replacingOccurrences`

```
var myString = "thisIsMyAutoGeneratedRandomString"
let parsed = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "AutoGeneratedRandom", with: "")
print(myString) //"thisIsMyString"
```

Comment: Hi @Emre i mentioned that it is auto generated string. I dont know what extactly it contains to replace it. Any how thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `prefix` for a simple solution

```
let firstPart = myString.prefix(8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift solution prefix or    `let lastPart = date.suffix(16)`